# Will Paginate pagination options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am trying to make the next and previous button more defined. Are there any predefined styles that are available to me using mislav-will_paginate

Comment: please update your question with more readable code! Why are there `<a>`-tags around the `link_to` helper? The `link_to` helper creates the `<a>`-tag!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the pagination helper; if you need something else, in my experience you're likely doing it wrong.

So just do

```
<%= will_paginate @people %>
```

And use this generic digg style link css:

```
.pagination { padding: 3px; margin: 3px; } 
.pagination a { padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px; margin: 2px; border: 1px solid #aaaadd; text-decoration: none; color: #000099; } 
.pagination a:hover, 
.pagination a:active { border: 1px solid #000099; color: #000; } 
.pagination span.current { padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px; margin: 2px; border: 1px solid #000099; font-weight: bold; background-color: #000099; color: #FFF; } 
.pagination span.disabled { padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px; margin: 2px; border: 1px solid #eee; color: #ddd; }
```

Comment: Could you explain span.disabled meaning?

Comment: @VvDPzZ will-paginate will create a span that is 'disabled' when you're on the first page and can't go previous. <span class="disabled prev_page">« Previous</span>